# I am trying to find the cause of multipart identifier could not been bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a stored procedure but I get an error.

> multipart identifier could not been bound

```
CREATE PROCEDURE salary_calculation
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM Attendance, EMPS      
    WHERE attendance.emp_id = emps.emp_id

    SELECT money_per_hour
    FROM EMPS

    INSERT INTO Attendance(SALARY)   
    VALUES (DATEDIFF(HOUR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CAST(' 10:10:00 PM' AS TIME))*EMPS.money_per_hour );


go
```

It shows the error I mentioned in the title surely I tried finding a solution but I couldn't

When I tried to delete the table specification "emps.money_per_hour" it gave me invalid column name error even though I'm pretty sure it's not

Just some extra info (there's 2 tables attendance and emps
emps has in it the money rate and id and attendance has the refrenced id and the entrance time and outro time so the procedure is supposed to calculate the salary using both of them)

Comment: FYI, it's 2021; you've had **29 years** to adopt the ANSI-92 JOIN syntax. Why are you *still* using that 32 years old implicit join syntax?

Comment: Yeah i guess this will do it i know it may feel a little bit cliche but i'm new to sql that's why i couldn't find it and thanks really for you your help

Answer (score 1):

You are using the values form of insert statement which doesn't allow you to reference a table. If you wish to reference a table you select from table after your insert statement not before. Please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

I think what you want is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE salary_calculation
AS
BEGIN
    -- Don't return a result set, and ensure any error rolls back the entire transaction
    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

    -- Best practice is explicit joins
    SELECT *
    FROM Attendance
    INNER JOIN EMPS ON attendance.emp_id = emps.emp_id;

    INSERT INTO Attendance(SALARY)   
        SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CAST(' 10:10:00 PM' AS TIME))*EMPS.money_per_hour)
        FROM EMPS;

    -- Return a status code, 0 all is well
    RETURN 0;
END;
GO
```